# How to create FolderBrowserDialog in Prism 6 WPF MVVM application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

In my WPF MVVM Prism 6 application I'm in need of dialog window for selecting of folders, like this:

[image]

(I bag your pardon for Russian in the dialog). As I know there is no this type of dialog in WPF. So I have a question: **How to create FolderBrowserDialog in modular Prism 6 WPF MVVM  application?** Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the WinForms [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is standard practice unless you want the dialog to have exactly the same UI as the rest of your application.

The same is done with the File Open and File Save dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM Dialogs aren't trivial, although there are several libraries out there to help you. Here's [my own solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) to the problem.